# Terraform disabling dataprep

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-dataprep

Hi all struggling to find a solution here so really hoping the community has achieved or can provide some suggestions on how to do it.

Summary:
Terraform is disabling dataprep on build. No docs on enabling dataprep with it or through gcloud

What I done:
Turned on through ui

What I need:
Ideally enable and maintain through terraform. Failing that anything that will stop Terraform disabling Dataprep

To anyone that can help me you are a hero

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Command Line Interface is not supported for Cloud Dataprep by Trifacta. No access to CLI or APIs!

https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Product-Limitations_60720399
https://docs.trifacta.com/display/SS/Product+Limitations